# Accessing Google Secrets from an application running on a Google Cloud VM instance - Assigning Cloud APIs to VM

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-oauth, google-compute-engine, google-secret-manager

I'm using Google Secrets to store API keys and other application specific "secrets". When I deploy my application to a VM instance using a docker container, I want it to access the Google Secrets using the VM's associated service account.

I have gotten this working using the following:

- Assigning the "Secret Manager Secret Accessor" permission to the Service Account.[image]
- Giving my VM access to all APIs:
- [image]

From a security perspective and recommended best practice, I don't want to give access to all APIs. The default access option doesn't work and I can't figure out from the list which options to enable to allow access to Google Secrets from my VM.

[image]

TLDR - Which Cloud API(s) do I need to give my Google Compute VM instance access to so that it can access  Google Secrets without giving it access to all of the Cloud APIs?

Comment: I think you're confusing OAuth Scopes and IAM. You should **not** use the default compute engine service account. Create a dedicated service account, give it IAM permissions to access the secrets you want it to access, then select that service account in the dropdown.

Comment: Also, the OAuth Scopes can only limit the roles that a service account already has. Using the screenshot in your question, selecting a service does NOT add a role to a service account. As Seth mentioned, the Compute Engine default service account has a lot of roles assigned which in itself makes using Google Cloud easier but must be reviewed from a security position.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Secret Manager documentation](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/access-control), you need the **cloud-platform** OAuth scope.

> **Note:** To access the Secret Manager API from within a Compute Engine instance or a Google Kubernetes Engine node (which is also a Compute Engine instance), the instance must have the cloud-platform OAuth scope. For more information about access scopes in Compute Engine, see Service account permissions in the Compute Engine documentation.

I'm not sure you can set this scope in the web UI, though you can set it through the command line.

#### Possible Alternative

What I do, rather than setting scopes on VMs, is create a service account specifically for the VMs (instead of using the default service account) and then give this service account access to specific resources (like the specific Secrets it should have access to, rather than all of them). When you do this in the web UI, the access scopes disappear and you are instructed to use IAM roles to control VM access like so:

[image: Custom Service Account]

Comment: I used your "Alternative Solution", setting up a service account with the required permissions. Worked with no issues. Thank you.