# Cant access secrets stored in Secret Manager from cloud dataproc(Pyspark)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, google-secret-manager, dataproc

I am trying to access secrets stored in GC Secret Manager from dataproc but I am not able to do so.
I have enabled Secrets Manager api and have added IAM role of Secret Manager Secret Accessor to my owner account and dataproc.
But I am trying to create/access secrets I get the following error:

> PermissionDenied: 403 Request had insufficient authentication scopes.

I am following the following tutorial present here[https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets?authuser=3]

Here is the code snippet:

```
def create_secret(project_id, secret_id):
"""
Create a new secret with the given name. A secret is a logical wrapper
around a collection of secret versions. Secret versions hold the actual
secret material.
"""

# Import the Secret Manager client library.
from google.cloud import secretmanager

# Create the Secret Manager client.
client = secretmanager.SecretManagerServiceClient()

# Build the resource name of the parent project.
parent = f"projects/{project_id}"

# Create the secret.
response = client.create_secret(
    request={
        "parent": parent,
        "secret_id": secret_id,
        "secret": {"replication": {"automatic": {}}},
    }
)

# Print the new secret name.
print("Created secret: {}".format(response.name))
```

Comment: Do you have access to the GCE instance that dataproc is running on? It looks like you're missing the correct oauth scope on the GCE instance: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/scopes#secretmanager

Comment: Yes I think I have access to GCE 
I belive I may be lacking some depedencies.

Comment: Then it's not about dependencies it's about starting the GCE instance with the right scopes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GCP VM Instance is not able to access secrets from Secret Manager despite of appropriate Roles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67151569/gcp-vm-instance-is-not-able-to-access-secrets-from-secret-manager-despite-of-app)

Comment: @AlexG Didnt work, 
Getting same error as above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Accessing Google Secrets from an application running on a Google Cloud VM instance - Assigning Cloud APIs to VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64506602/accessing-google-secrets-from-an-application-running-on-a-google-cloud-vm-instan)

Comment: HI @sethvargo,
I created a service account with all the required permissions and then created a dataproc cluster using that service account but still I am not able to  access secrets

Comment: Did you grant the `cloud-platform` OAuth scope to the Dataproc VMs? https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/service-accounts

Answer (score 0):

When you create your Dataproc cluster, you need to add the [additional scopes](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/clusters/create#--scopes), but there isn't a specific scope for Secret Manager like there is for BigQuery or Pub/Sub.  For Secret Manager, you need to add the [cloud-platform](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/creating-and-accessing-secrets#:%7E:text=To%20use%20Secret%20Manager%20on,with%20the%20cloud%2Dplatform%20scope.&text=To%20run%20this%20code%2C%20first,the%20Secret%20Manager%20C%23%20SDK.) oauth scope.